# Fb.UI Dialogs are displaying in Popups instead of an iframe

Tags: php, facebook, oauth

I am attempting to implement some Facebook popups for my native FB app but I am having inconsistent results when it comes to how the dialog boxes pop up. For instance, when I click on a certain button this is called:

```
    FB.ui({
        method:'apprequests',
        message:'Check out this app!',
        data:'123456789',
        title:'Awesome!'
    },
    function(response) {
        if(response != null){
            //other stuff
        }
    });
```

In Safari, Opera, Chrome, and IE this works as expected and the popup appears in an iframe over my app. In Firefox 6, however, it is popping up in a separate popup window. This is something I had an issue with in the past but solved by implementing OAuth. My OAuth url is formed in the following way:

```
"http://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth/?scope=user_birthday,email&client_id=" . APP_ID . "&redirect_uri=" . urlencode(FB_URL)
```

Has something changed today that I need to ask for further permissions? Thank you.

**UPDATE**
I wanted to add to this that ultimately it proved to be nothing wrong with Facebook. Apparently something was set improperly in my FFox profile and resetting it fixed the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try setting display="iframe" per this [guide](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/) but when you need to prompt users for extended permissions you normally can't use iframe.

Comment: Thank you so much! I could have sworn this used to work without having to specify the display as iframe but regardless you saved a good bit of time.