# App Request Dialog, Popups in a new window

Tags: user-interface, facebook-graph-api, facebook, facebook-ui

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Fb.UI Dialogs are displaying in Popups instead of an iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7246169/fb-ui-dialogs-are-displaying-in-popups-instead-of-an-iframe)

I got this code for application request dialog:

```js
FB.ui({ 
    method: "apprequests", 
    message: "You have a gift!  Click accept to see what it is!",
    data: gift, //This will be passed back to you when a user accepts the request
    title: "Send "+giftname+" to 50 friends!"
  },
  function(response) {
    if (response && response.request_ids) {
      alert('Your gift has been sent!');
    } else {
      alert('You must select some friends to send gifts to!');
    }
  });
```

and it seems like the dialog is opening in a new window. I don't want this, I would like to popup the request dialog within a Facebook Styled POPUP, same happens with the feed dialog.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting display="iframe" per this [guide](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/) but when you need to prompt users for extended permissions you normally can't use iframe.

Comment: If two questions have the same answer, don't answer them both, instead vote to close one of them as a duplicate.

Comment: Ok I voted. Normally FB posts dont get enough duplicate votes to ever get closed.